# Manual xpath override for import.io with dt tag

Tags: html, xpath, web-crawler, import.io

Writing xpath overrides is still a struggle for me after going through import.io's training blogs and W3schools. I'm trying to extract attribute values from a site where the information isn't always in exactly the same place so I know I need to write an xpath override. The HTML is:

```
<dt>3TG:</dt> 
<dd>Does not contain 3TG</dd>
<dt>Contract Catalog Item:</dt>
<dd>Y</dd> 
<dt>Diameter:</dt>
<dd>3/8"</dd>
<dt>Diameter-Thread Size:</dt>
<dd>3/8"-16</dd>
<dt>Finish:</dt>
<dd>Zinc</dd>
<dt>Grade:</dt>
<dd>5</dd>
<dt>Length:</dt>
<dd>1"</dd>
<dt>Material:</dt>
<dd>Steel</dd>
```

The xpath is

```
//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/dl/dt[4]
```

I have tried

```
//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/dl/dt[contains(text(), "Finish")]/following-sibling::dt/text()
```

and

```
//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/dl/td/dd[.="Finish:"]/following::dd
```

But no luck. I am not sure if it's following or a following sibling. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the site? What is the exact data do you are looking to extract?

Comment: You are specifying too much the order of elements. If the website changes the layout between requests, the data that was in div[1] for example can now be in div[2] and you are not able to get the correct result. Can you provide the website please? You can also use the OR operator and cover the cases you know. Some data can fit in more than one OR condition but you can clean it afterwards. The important thing is getting the data!

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[text()="XXXX"]/following-sibling::*
```

Change XXXX to the thing you want

EG: If you want to know the info about "3TG:" it would look like this.

```
//*[text()="3TG:"]/following-sibling::*

<dt>3TG:</dt> 
<dd>Does not contain 3TG</dd>
```

So the xPath finds any element with the TEXT "3TG:", regardless of the tag, and then looks at the following sibling (the thing next to it).

To make it more specific to your definition list you can add more specificity like this:

```
//dt[text()="3TG:"]/following-sibling::dd

<dt>3TG:</dt> 
<dd>Does not contain 3TG</dd>
```